# Can I sue an at Will employer?

Tags: banking

I work in Minnesota which is an at will state at a nationwide banking institution. I was hired in June and was told I would be doing the work of what I now know to be a site in a different state. To make matters worse they changed my job title to something I feel as a former talent recruiter as less employable. My manager has even told me that they hired me knowing that the role as well as the title
Would change. Is there anything I can do other than look for a different job ?

Comment: Do you have an offer letter or contract that states either your expected or current title, or job functions?

Comment: Umm I will have to find my offer letter . If it says “other duties assigned by the manager “ would that not be in my best interest

Answer (score 1):

The manager is basically right. An at will employee can have their job terminated or relocated, and can have title's changed, for no reason.

If the company knew that you would be relocated at the time of hiring, there is arguably a misrepresentation issue although proving damages would be hard.

Failing to accept the relocation might be grounds to be eligible for unemployment insurance although you may not have worked long enough to be eligible for it.